# PowerBI generates an SQL query that is too deeply nested. How to fix?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

In PowerBI Query builder, I create the following query:

```
let
    SV_DATA = Sql.Database("my.ip.add.ress", "SV_DATA", [CreateNavigationProperties=false]),
    ImportanceTables = Table.SelectRows(SV_DATA, each Text.EndsWith([Name], "_IMPORTANCE_RATINGS")),
    Importances = Table.Combine(ImportanceTables[Data])
in
    Importances
```

As you can see, the query looks for all tables that end in `_IMPORTANCE_RATINGS` and combines them into a single table.  (This is necessary because there are thousands of `*_IMPORTANCE_RATINGS` tables and they are added and dropped over time;  I therefore can't hard-code them).

The preview works perfectly.

However when I try to apply the query in my report, I get the following error from SQL Server:

> Failed to save modifications to the server.  Error returned: 'OLE DB or ODBC error: [DataSource.Error] Microsoft SQL: Some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply.  Rewrite the query or break it up into smaller queries..'.

However, I don't see any way to simplify my work in PowerBI.  It seems that it is PowerBI itself that makes the SQL query too complex.

Suggestions?

Thanks,
DC

Comment: Are the columns of `ImportanceTables` uniform? What is the count of these tables?

Comment: Yes, the columns are uniform, but just in case I explicitly stated them:
`{"PROG_ID", "RESPONSE_ID", "COMPOSITE", "PRACTICE_NUMBER", "IMPORTANCE_RATING", "CHANNEL", "BREAKOUT", "SOURCE"}`.


Each table has ~10K rows.

Comment: Then I would avoid doing this. I suppose it lengthengs SQL query and makes it even more complex. However I may be wrong here.

Comment: How many such tables is there?

Comment: @Eugene:  You just restated my question: given that my implementation is not working because the SQL is too nested, what is my alternative?  BTW, your answer below does not work because `ImportanceTable[Data]` is not a list of tables.

Comment: "How many such tables is there?" As stated in the question, "there are thousands of *_IMPORTANCE_RATINGS tables".

Comment: I misspelled it. Fixing the answer now. If it still doesn't work, try inserting `Test = ImportanceTables[Data]` after `ImportanceTables` step, and reply what does it return.

Comment: Try removing `[CreateNavigationProperties=false]`, as PQ generates quite different SQL then. However I can see no nested queries during trace (i traced similar query in SQL Profiler). Perhaps you can trace your query too?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Importances = Table.Combine(ImportanceTables[Data], {"PROG_ID", "RESPONSE_ID", "COMPOSITE", "PRACTICE_NUMBER", "IMPORTANCE_RATING", "CHANNEL", "BREAKOUT", "SOURCE"} )
```

or even

```
Importances = Table.Combine(ImportanceTables[Data])
```

, if columns are uniform across tables.

`Table.Combine()` accepts a list of tables as first argument.

However if your table count is too large you can potentially face other problems.

Comment: Well, the good news:  your suggestion simplified my query.  I will update the question shortly.

The bad news:  still getting the "nested too deep" error.